# Xcode - debugging library built outside project

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.5, xcode4.6

I have a C library whose code resides in say /repos1/clib. I build that from the command line using the latest iOS sdk to create clib.a (including a debug build for the simulator) which I copy to an iOS project say in /repos2/proj.

I have been using this setup for several years. The old C library very occasionally might require some debugging and I was pleased by the fact that Xcode simply stepped into the library code that was outside the project (inside repos1) without having to do any setup - it just worked.
But this was up until a few Xcode versions ago. I am not sure exactly when it changed - perhaps when they moved from gcc to llvm? - since I very seldom needed to debug the C code, but for a while now I only get dissasembly when I try to debug the C library from the iOS project (including at least references to the C file name & line number). For the few times I need to debug it is very inconvenient (I create a temp project that includes the C code).

So, any idea why it worked before and doesn't now? Where should I look? Could it be the way I build the C library, maybe there was a flag in gcc I was using that does not have an equivalent in llvm (I can find and post the old build command I was using if it is relevant)? Is the issue in Xcode and there is a way to tell it where to look for the sources?

Thanks!

Edit: To make it clear, I can add the C library either as the source or as a subproject in Xcode, however for reasons that are out of scope this is not helpful for this specific project. So, can it work like it used to with older Xcode versions? If not, it would still be interesting to know why not.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach is to create a library project in Xcode, one for iOS (there is a template for it), then when you get that to build add that project to your app, make sure the lib is a dependency and gets linked. There are many tutorials on the web how to do this.

Then as iOS evolves and new architectures (armv7s) arrive you simply update both projects.

Comment: There is a good reason the library is not added to the project normally (and I have to make a temp project like you say just to debug when needed once a year or so). So for the specifics of this project the way it worked before was very convenient, and I would like to see if I can get that back.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same issue.

I tried resetting in library/application project all options related to symbol stripping and copy application project to same truecrypt drive as library project but it didn't help.

In my case it appeared it was an app project issue. Same library could be debugged in another app project with source code so that was a clue.

I had more than one version of the same library in app project and set only target membership to choose which should be used. Not sure if that could affect my app project somehow.
Nevertheless after deleting all libraries and copying them to app project again I was able to debug libraries with access to source code.